# How do I do something like numpy where(2darray ==0, 1darray, 1darray)

Tags: python, numpy, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I'm working on a mutation function for a genetic algorithm, but I'm pretty new to numpy.

The default mutation method looks like this:

```
whereMutate = np.random.rand(np.shape(population)[0],np.shape(population)[1])
population[np.where(whereMutate < self.mutationProb)] = 1 - population[np.where(whereMutate < self.mutationProb)]
```

The default mutationprob is set to 1/chromosome length. Population contains a different chromosome on each row and chromosomes are 561 long, with a 0 or 1 at each position.

What I was trying to do is to set the probability of mutation based upon the frequency of 0s and 1s for that chromosome, so that when a chromosome with very few 1s mutates it is just as likely to switch a 0 to a 1 as it is to go the other way.

Currently I have something like this:

```
mProbOne = 0.5/np.count_nonzero(population, axis=1)
mProbZero = 0.5/np.count_nonzero(population == 0, axis=1)
probs = np.where(population == 0, mProbZero, mProbOne)
# Something like the above ought to give me a 2d array 
# with probability of mutation for each position in the chromosome,
# separately for each chromosome
whereMutate = np.random.rand(np.shape(population)[0],np.shape(population)[1]
population[np.where(whereMutate < probs)] = 1-population[np.where(whereMutate < self.mutationProb)]
```

The last two lines are just the same as the currently existing two lines for the case where mutation probability is fixed.
My issue is line 3 above. mProbZero and mProbOne are 1d numpy arrays. I am getting a

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,5) (2,) (2,)
```

Follow-up: the following code seems to work, though it's probably about 4 lines more than necessary... is there any way to do this better?

```
mProbZero = 0.5/np.count_nonzero(population == 0, axis=1)
mProbOne = 0.5/np.count_nonzero(population, axis=1)
probs = np.zeros(np.shape(population))
probs[np.where(population == 0)] = mProbZero[np.where(population == 0)[0]]
probs[np.where(population == 1)] = mProbOne[np.where(population == 1)[0]]
whereMutate = np.random.rand(np.shape(population)[0],np.shape(population)[1])
population[np.where(whereMutate < self.mutationProb)] = 1 - population[np.where(whereMutate < self.mutationProb)]
```

Comment: Do you understand `numpy` array broadcasting?  `where` takes 3 arguments, which will be scalars or arrays.  If arrays, their shapes have to be compatible - that is broadcastable.  Did you even look at the `shapes` that you cut off ...?

Comment: I don't really understand it too well. The shapes don't match. It's something like (nChromosomes, lengthChromosome) and (nChromosomes, ) 

Is there a good shorthand for doing what I'm trying to do? :O

Comment: Something like this seems to work, but I think there's probably a much better way of doing it?

mProbZero = 0.5/np.count_nonzero(population == 0, axis=1)
mProbOne = 0.5/np.count_nonzero(population, axis=1)
probs = np.zeros(np.shape(population))
probs[np.where(population == 0)] = mProbZero[np.where(population == 0)[0]]
probs[np.where(population == 1)] = mProbOne[np.where(population == 1)[0]]

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to format that code in a comment... :(

Comment: always put code in question, not in comment.

Comment: So the condition has 10 values (5,2).  But the the alternatives only 2 each?  If those had a (2,1) shape the code should run.  But is that result you want?

Answer (score 0):

A (2,3) condition with (2,1) values:

```
In [470]: np.where(np.array([[1,0,1],[0,1,1]]), np.array([['a'],['b']]), np.array([['c'],['d']]))    
Out[470]: 
array([['a', 'c', 'a'],
       ['d', 'b', 'b']], dtype='<U1')
```

With (3,) values ( (1,3) by broadcasting):

```
In [471]: np.where(np.array([[1,0,1],[0,1,1]]), np.array(['a','b','c']), np.array(['d','e','f']))    
Out[471]: 
array([['a', 'e', 'c'],
       ['d', 'b', 'c']], dtype='<U1')
```

In both cases the result shape matches the condition's.

Comment: OK thanks. So effectively all I needed to do was change the shape from (2, ) to (2, 1)? (2, 1) would be broadcastable as it has the same dimension as (5, 2) while (2, ) does not?
I'm still a bit of a numpy numpty. I need to learn to understand the difference between these two shapes - (2, 1) and (2, ) better. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Remember `(2,)` is a 1 element tuple.  That's basic Python. `(2,1)` is a 2 element tuple.  So when talking about shapes, that's a difference between 1d and 2d - the number of dimensions.  And in `numpy` an array can have 0, 1, 2 or more dimensions.  Arrays can have the same elements, while their shapes are different.

Comment: Ahh right, gotcha! Thanks! I guess I just find it somewhat counter-intuitive to think of even the (2,1) case to be a 2d array, but I guess from the perspective of the tuple describing its shape, that does make more sense. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using a binary genetic algorithm. that means in your mutation you need switch 1 to 0 and 0 to 1. I don't how your population looks like.
for a simple method, you can modify this code. Here I use select random position, that you can change to mutation probability.

```
   def binary_mutation(parent1):
        posi = random.randint(0, len(parent1)-1)
        if parent1[posi] == 1:
            parent1[posi] = 0
        elif parent1[posi] == 0:
            parent1[posi] = 1
        return parent1
```

Comment: Thanks. I get that - but was trying to change the probabilities so that a chromosome with 20 1s and 541 0s is just as likely to switch 1->0 as 0->1. That's why I was looking at ways to set the probability of mutation depending on the current value.